# Dynamically loading Java Script files

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know if there is a way to dynamically load some JS files before "$(document).ready" gets called. These JS files should be loaded and available in the ready event handler.

Does jquery provide a way to do this?

The issue here (as you might expect) is the ability to load a specific localized version of my JS files depending on whichever locale/language is selected.

Thanks

Comment: If you've found them helpful, please accept to your previous questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want in pure javascript you can try this.

```
   var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
   var script= document.createElement('script');
   script.type= 'text/javascript';
   script.onreadystatechange= function () {
      if (this.readyState == 'complete'){
          //Your can write your code here
      };
   }
   script.src= 'script.js';
   head.appendChild(script);
```

Alertnatively you can use jQuery's `getScript` method

```
$.getScript("script.js", function(){
    //Your can write your code here
});
```

Comment: Is this synchronous or asynchronous. In other words after the call to "$.getScript("script.js");" is the script from that js available in the very next line? Or should we have to wait for the callback function to execute?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
jQuery.getScript("url here")
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/